# Table of shared edges for a Voronoi tesslleation

Tags: r, maps, polygon, voronoi, spatstat

I'm attempting to create a table of polygon neighbors based on a Voronoi tessellation (aka Dirichlet tessellations or Thiessen polygons) generated by the `dirichlet()` function of the `spatstat` library. For example, in the figure below, the upper right and bottom right tiles would each have 2 neighbors, the center right tile 4 neighbors, and the remaining two tiles 3 neighbors each. I want to capture the neighbor pairs in a table, and ideally capture the length of the boundary line that they share: e.g., 'Tile1', 'Tile2', 'shared_edge_length'.

Initially, I attempted to loop through and compare each pair of polygons in the tessellation using `intersect.tess()`, `intersect.own()`, as well as `polyclip` functions, but I'm guessing these don't work because the tiles are by definition not overlapping in area, despite sharing edges. Is there a simple function to accomplish this (the alternative being to loop through the `$bdry` points perhaps)? It seems like the `regeos` package has `gTouches`, but I couldn't find something similar for `spatstat`.

This is my current non-working approach:

```
library(spatstat)
points <- ppp(x=c(-77.308703, -77.256582, -77.290600,  -77.135668, -77.097144),
         y=c(39.288603, 39.147019, 39.372818, 39.401898, 39.689203),
         window=owin(xrange=c(-77.7,-77), yrange=c(39.1, 39.7)))
vt <- dirichlet(points) # Dirichlet tesselation
plot(vt)

tilesA <- tiles(vt)
n_tiles <- length(tilesA)
boundary_calcs <- data.frame('area1_id'=numeric(), 'area2_id'=numeric(), 'neighbor'=logical()) # Store boundary pairs
for (i in 1:n_tiles) {
  for (j in 1:n_tiles) {
    intersection <- intersect.owin(tilesA[[i]], tilesA[[j]], fatal=FALSE) # does not work
    if (!is.empty(intersection)) {
      boundary_calcs[nrow(boundary_calcs)+1, ] <- c(i, j, TRUE) # add to data table as new row
} } }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function was provided by the package authors. It uses the fact that the `deldir()` function's `dirsgs` structure outputs the start/end coordinates of each line in the tessellation along with the point indices. These can be converted to a `psp` line segment pattern which can easily provide the length of each segment using `lengths.psp()`. The code below produces a table with one row for each of the 7 edges that can be seen in the plot above.

```
library(spatstat)
library(deldir)
points <- ppp(x=c(-77.308703, -77.256582, -77.290600,  -77.135668, -77.097144),
         y=c(39.288603, 39.147019, 39.372818, 39.401898, 39.689203),
         window=owin(xrange=c(-77.7,-77), yrange=c(39.1, 39.7)))

sharededge <- function(X) {
   verifyclass(X, "ppp")
   Y <- X[as.rectangle(X)]
   dX <- deldir(Y)
   DS <- dX$dirsgs
   xyxy <- DS[,1:4]
   names(xyxy) <- c("x0","y0","x1","y1")
   sX <- as.psp(xyxy,window=dX$rw)
   marks(sX) <- 1:nobjects(sX)
   sX <- sX[as.owin(X)]
   tX <- tapply(lengths.psp(sX), marks(sX), sum)
   jj <- as.integer(names(tX))
   ans <- data.frame(ind1=DS[jj,5], 
                     ind2=DS[jj,6], 
                     leng=as.numeric(tX))
   return(ans)
}

shared_edge_lengths <- sharededge(points)
```

The output stored in `shared_edge_lengths`:

```
  ind1 ind2       leng
1    2    1 0.17387212
2    3    1 0.13444458
3    4    1 0.05791519
4    4    2 0.10039321
5    4    3 0.25842530
6    5    3 0.09818828
7    5    4 0.17162429
```

Answer (score 0):

I just asked Rolf Turner who is author of the package `deldir`, and he provided the code below for finding the number of neighbours for each tile. I haven't yet looked at your wish to "ideally capture the length of the boundary line that they share".

```
x <- c(-77.308703, -77.256582, -77.290600,  -77.135668, -77.097144)
y <- c(39.288603, 39.147019, 39.372818, 39.401898, 39.689203)
rw <- c(-77.7,-77,39.1,39.7)
require(deldir)
dxy <- deldir(x,y,rw=rw)

dxy$summary$n.tside
```

Comment: After a more detailed reading of the question, I see that this doesn't provide an answer at all. It is just the number of neighbours and not indicating which pairs are neighbours. Hopefully, I will have time to get back to this later. (You could try `delaunay` for finding neighbouring pairs, but I'm absolutely not sure it is useful. Conceptually the Delaunay graph is the relevant thing to look at.).

Comment: thanks for the notes. I've been exploring your suggestion but haven't found a way to employ a Delaunay graph. Is there not a way to do this using pairs of the tiles already created with `dirichlet`?